# angular 5, Keeping value on inputs and adding it to JS object

Tags: input, output, angular5, ngfor, ngmodel

I am making a web tool in angular 5 to help in the creation of  new XML.

I am having trouble passing around the values of inputs and keeping them in the  same input at the same time.

I Have a form with an event of ngSubmit that uses as a paremeter the reference of an ngForm

```html
<form class="form-group" (ngSubmit)="createSimpleTypeList(f)" #f="ngForm" >
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12" >
                <button class="btn btn-danger flex ">Construir Json!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>

    <div class="container" *ngFor="let type of objSimpleType;let i =index">
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="type.name" name="nameType"/> 
                <br>
                Inserte el nombre del tipo:     
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text"    [(ngModel)]="type.type"   name="type"/> 
                <br>
                Inserte el tipo:    
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="number"  [(ngModel)]="type.min"  name="min"/> 
                <br>
                Inserte minimo: 
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="number"  [(ngModel)]="type.max" name="max"/> 
                <br>
                Inserte maximo: 
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="checkbox" name="number" />   Numero?
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <hr>
</form>
```

---

This is the createSimpleTypeList method

```js
console.log(form.value.nameType);
this.objSimpleType.push({
    '-name': form.value.nameType,
    'xsd:restriction': {
        '-base': form.value.type,
        'xsd:minLength': {
            '-value': form.value.min
        },
        'xsd:maxLenght': {
            '-value': form.value.max
        }
    }
});
this.typeList.emit(form.value.nameType);
this.sharedNameSpace.emit(this.namespace);
```

---

The problem I am having is that I have not found a way to push new items into objSimpleType, without erasing the value of inputs, and if I manage to not erase the value of the inputs then the values of the form wont push.

this is how it looks.[how the inputs work right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRyXj.png)

This is what I need

[How the inputs should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZYZP.png) 
I am still new to angular, and I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: You're probably going to want to look into using Reactive forms as you're constructing a form with an array of controls in it. Here's a nice tutorial: https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/. Come back with a link to a minimal stackblitz to help people help you

Comment: Hey I am still looking into the link you sent, but my bad, here is the stackblitz!

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-irhdtk?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput%2Finput.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for the blitz link, although i'm still unsure of what you're trying to achieve. When you press enter on the input, a new item is added to the array, and as the array is used to dynamically create the form, you get a new form set with an empty input added to the bottom - the input you were typing in still has the value entered in it?

Comment: Thank you so much! With the help of your link and other texts on the internet I have found the solution to my problem. Thank you so much !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I have looked found the solution, I had two mistakes in the code above.

First my logic was not well executed, I needed to work with unique IDs,and call them dynamically.

Second, I was having trouble to call them , and after reading a lot, I found that I can call the parameters of a Json with brackets[].

"form.value['nameType' + this.i]" --Something like this is what i Needed.